# How did this character become a priestess?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy, Vol. 2,

> Ayesha is introduced as a high priestess of the Sovereign.

I read her [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kismet_(Marvel_Comics)) page, which makes no reference to any religious affiliation.  She has the power to bring life back into a body if the spirit has not left yet, but there is no religion associated with it.

> **How did Ayesha become a priestess, and what is the Sovereign religion?**